# How to change default debug perspective in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, debugger

While debugging, Eclipse opens its Debug perspective. I've made some changes to this perspective and saved it with other name.

Is there a way to change default debug perspective to one created, so it would open when debug starts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the **Preferences** menu choose: **Run/Debug -> Perspectives**

There you can select for each *Application Type* the default perspective for *Debug* and *Run*.